# How manipulate res.locals object in request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I'm using `node-restful` in my project, I want replace my date properties with `moment`.

When I try like below;

```
var QuestionResource = app.user = restful.model('Question', questionSchema)
        .methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);

    QuestionResource
        .after('get', function(req, res, next) {
            res.locals.bundle.forEach(function(question) {
               res.locals.bundle[res.locals.bundle.indexOf(question)].created_at = moment(question.created_at).fromNow()
            })
            next()
        })
```

Response data not changed. Why? How can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved my problem with helps **node-restful** community on github.

Looking into this, it looks like it's because the models that are returned are not plain objects, but an instance of a mongoose object.

In post processing, manually call toObject()

```
res.locals.bundle.forEach(function(question, idx, questions) {
  questions[idx] = question.toObject();
  questions[idx].created_at = moment(question.created_at).fromNow()
})
```